# Не могу вытащить значение из формы

Tags: javascript, html

При нажатии на кнопку `solve` у меня должны вытаскиваться значения из создаваемых в массиве `inp` полей.

Но вытаскивается только последняя строчка и заполняется весь массив тоже последней строчкой.

Где ошибка и как ее исправить?

```js
decide = document.getElementById('decide');
inp = [, ];
m = [, ]
decide.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  row = parseInt(document.getElementById('resurse').value); //строки(ресурсы)
  column = parseInt(document.getElementById('pred').value); //столбцы(предприятия)
  lab = document.getElementById('label');
  lab.innerHTML = 'Введите данные<br>';
  console.log('row = ', row, 'column = ', column);
  for (var i = 0; i < row; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < column; j++) {
      inp[i, j] = document.createElement('input');
      inp[i, j].id = 'inp';
      inp[i, j].type = 'number';
      lab.appendChild(inp[i, j]);
    }
    br = document.createElement('br');
    lab.appendChild(br);
  }

  solve = document.createElement('button');
  solve.id = 'solve';
  solve.innerHTML = 'Решить';
  label.appendChild(solve);

  solve.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    for (var i = 0; i < row; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < column; j++) {
        console.log('[', i, '][', j, '] = ', parseInt(inp[i, j].value));
      }
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<form id="form" class="form">
    <label>
        <p>Введите количество распределяемых ресурсов</p>
        <input type="number" id='resurse'>
        <p>Введите количество предприятий</p>
        <input type='number' id="pred">
    </label>
    <label>
        <button id="decide">Вводить дальше</button>
    </label>
    <br>
</form>
<form id="form-data" class="form-data">
    <div id='form-data__button' class="form-data__button">
        <label id="label"></label>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: В какой строчке вы вытягиваете данные и добавляете их в массив?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Двумерные массивы в js делаются так:

```
var inp = [];
...
  for (var i = 0; i < row; i++) {
    inp[i] = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < column; j++) {
      inp[i][j] = document.createElement('input');
      inp[i][j].id = 'inp';
      inp[i][j].type = 'number';
      lab.appendChild(inp[i][j]);
    }
    br = document.createElement('br');
    lab.appendChild(br);
  }
...
  solve.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    for (var i = 0; i < row; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < column; j++) {
        console.log('[', i, '][', j, '] = ', parseInt(inp[i][j].value));
      }
    }
  })
```

Добавьте в Ваш код `console.log(inp);`, и Вы увидите в чем дело: массив `inp` у Вас - одномерный, а второй индекс просто игнорируется.