# помогите понять, как исправить ошибку Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: commentsListWidth is not a function"

Tags: javascript, vue.js

мне просто нужно установить ширину списка, но появляется ошибка
Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: commentsListWidth is not a function"
как ее исправить?

```
commentsSlider(direction){
        // элементы слайдера
        let commentsList = this.$el.querySelector('.comments__list');
        // длина двух элементов слайдера
        let commentsListWidth = commentsList.clientWidth;
        console.log(commentsListWidth);
        // элементы одного слайда
        let commentsItem = this.$el.querySelectorAll('.comments__item');
        console.log(commentsItem);
        // установка ширины списка = произведение длины двух элементов на количество слайдов
        commentsListWidth(commentsItem.length * commentsListWidth);
        switch(direction){
            case 'next':
                console.log('rigth');
                break;
            case 'prev':
                console.log('left');
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Исправлять нужно весь код (переписывать полностью), так как ошибкой является прямая работа с DOM в элементе экземпляра Vue - проще говоря, это один большой костыль. Если уж не нужна реактивность в документе, есть `Vue.observable`, который реализует ее только для JS-объекта...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Переименуйте локальную переменную.

```
    let commentsListWidth1 = commentsList.clientWidth;
    console.log(commentsListWidth1);
    // элементы одного слайда
    let commentsItem = this.$el.querySelectorAll('.comments__item');
    console.log(commentsItem);
    // установка ширины списка = произведение длины двух элементов на количество слайдов
    commentsListWidth(commentsItem.length * commentsListWidth1);
```

---

Вы вот здесь ничего не забыли сделать?

[Не могу вытащить значение из формы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/911328/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%83-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d1%8b)